# How to call a JQL query in Python

Tags: python, jql

I am working on a script in Python that will call the JQL script. How do I go about this?

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred+order+by+duedate
```

Assume the above is the JQL query.

This is what I have so far but it's getting an "invalid syntax" error.

```
from grt import executeScript

querystring = "curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"      http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key"
executeScript(querystring)
```

This is my error:

```
      File "/home/.spyder2/temp.py", line 19
    querystring = "curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"      http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key"
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't open/close the string properly:

```
querystring = "curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"      http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key"
```

should be:

```
querystring = """curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=QA+order+by+duedate&fields=id,key"""
```

because the string itself contains double-quotes.

Comment: Or you could use `'""'` syntax